# Ipfilter.dat for Utorrent, does it matter whether the IPs are sorted?

Tags: utorrent

I've got an Ipfilter.dat file containing IPs I want to block in my Utorrent. Does it matter whether those IPs are sorted asc/descending?

And how can I actually check if those IPs are incorporated and used in Utorrent other than enabling it in utorrent via ***ipfilter.enable***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is unimportant - uTorrent will merge any overlapping ranges automatically the first time it loads the ipfilter.dat.

There's no quick way to check that a specific IP is blocked as far as I know, just enable logging of IP blocked events (right click the log, IIRC) and see if anything comes up during normal use.